# What should I put in my .zprofile to regain access to $HOME/.zshrc?

Tags: android, flutter, shell, zsh, apple-m1

So I'm installing flutter for the first time on a M1 Mac and I'm following the docs on the flutter site I need to edit $HOME/.zshrc but get the

`"Permission denied."`

I've made sure the terminal has full access so its not that.. I really think the issue was that I was lacking a .zprofile ... So I created it but I'm not sure what goes in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers:

1. From the error you shared, it seems that you are trying to run it instead of opening it (for editing). Here is the output when I tried the same

```
aditbhardwj@MacBook-Air ~ % ~/.zshrc
zsh: permission denied: /Users/aditbhardwj/.zshrc
```

2. It is not present by default. You have to create it.
3. `.zprofile` is sourced upon login.
   `.zshrc` is sourced upon starting of a new shell. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where)
4. With regard to installing Flutter, I don't have anything relevant in `.zprofile` but I do have the `JAVA_HOME` set and path to `flutter/bin` added in `.zshrc`. Refer [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path).
5. `/etc/zshrc` and `~/.zshrc` are different.